# Удаление элемента контейнера map через итератор

Tags: c++, stl, map, итераторы, контейнеры

Имеется контейнер `map`, в котором я циклом

`for (auto it = A.begin(); it != A.end(); ++it)`

иду по всем элементам.
В какой-то момент, необходимо удалить некоторый элемент. При этом должна оставаться возможность идти по циклу, т.е. итератор `it` должен остаться и после инкремента должен указывать на корректный элемент (следующий за удаленным).
Как это реализовать? Есть подозрение, что для этого нужно переписать сам цикл, но как по другому идти по всем элементам, я не знаю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, поскольку [`map::erase` возвращает итератор, указывающий на элемент за удаленным](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase), то я бы просто перенес `++it` в тело цикла, выполняя инкремент итератора только если текущий не удален. Если удален - это по сути и есть инкремент...